# Aria Templates animations

Tags: ariatemplates

I am trying to achieve `sliding animation effect` using `AT`.

I checked `aria.utils.css.animations`, but i am not clear with the syntax and feel that `cfg beans parameteres` are limited.

**For Ex**: I want to achieve the `animation effect to slide an un-animated ul element` with a `timing of 200ms` and have to execute a function as soon as animation is completed.

The `jquery code` is shown below.

```
$('#slides ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : -250}, 200,function(){ });
```

can I have `respective functionality` using `AT`. I tried with the following code `to slide` an element.

```
aria.utils.css.Animations.start("slide",({'from':aria.utils.Dom.getDomElementsChildByTagName(slides, "li")[0]}),
```

but of no use.

I need a working example of änimations using AT. Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes so far the cfg bean is limited and it is possible only to define few things and between them the timing is not included.

You can slide left an element using the "slide" animation and you can call a function adding a listener to the event "animationend" and execute your function.

Here the code to do what you are trying to do:

```
var animate = new aria.utils.css.Animations();
var cfg = {
    from : aria.utils.Dom.getDomElementsChildByTagName(slides, "li")[0]
};

animate.$on({
    "animationend" : animationComplete,
    scope : this
});

animate.start("slide", cfg);
```

About examples, we are writing the documentation of the examples that we have, so I hope we will publish them soon.